# Date missing from timestamp in mysql log

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian

Currently, my log entries look like:

| time | message |
| --- | --- |
| 03:53:08 PM | ERROR |
| 05:40:32 PM | ERROR |
| ... | ... |

I want the date included, like this:

| time | message |
| --- | --- |
| 06/30/2022 03:53:08 PM | ERROR |
| 06/30/2022 05:40:32 PM | ERROR |
| ... | ... |

My global variables:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%log%'
```

| Variable_name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| binlog_format | MIXED |
| date_format | %Y-%m-%d |
| datetime_format | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s |
| default_week_format | 0 |
| innodb_default_row_format | dynamic |
| innodb_file_format |  |
| mysql56_temporal_format | ON |
| time_format | %H:%i:%s |

My DBMS version:

`@@version` is `10.5.15-MariaDB-0+deb11u1`

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing your my.cnf [mysqld] section to include:

```
time_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s
```

That should make the `time_format` the same as `datetime_format` and might be your answer.

Create a backup of your existing `my.cnf` file just in case you make a mistake while editing it.

Stop/start the instance and see what your log in question has with this change in place, please.